# Retargetable assembler

Tags: assembly

I'm looking for an assembler which I could easily retarget for the byte code of a simple VM, ideally with a configuration file, if not, written in Ada, C, C++, Java, Python or Rust. Simplicity of retargeting is more important than the feature set; for instance I do not need macro processing. The desired output format should be little more than an memory image with an expected load address and expected starting one.

I've looked at GNU and LLVM tools, but the barrier of entry seems higher than what I'd like for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have my doubts you will find such thing. Per se Assembler is a low level language which is directly bind with processor architecture. Also it is created for specific architecture around the processor (like MMU, FPU (if it's outside of processor)). You can check in GNU for cross compilers but they are separated programs for specific architecture/processor families.

Comment: Well, I've used in the past such an assembler driven by an external table. It was for DOS 30 years ago and I've no more access to it. Obviously some instructions may not fit the already provided patterns, but that's why I'm ready to have to write some code.